# Dropdown Navigation Menus - need help for mobile and touch devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, navbar, touchscreen

Hi my website has a main navigation menu that works perfect on desktops.  Hover of mouse opens the dropdown menu and the parent menu items are also clickable links (instead of '#').

The problem is with mobile and touch devices. Since these devices don't have 'hover', when I click on a parent category I am taken directly to the link.  How can I make it so the first click opens the dropdown, and have the parent menu links still work on the second click?

Should I switch my dropdown menu settings from "open on hover" to "click" and then use css and jquery to enable hover on non-touch devices (i.e. desktop)?

I am a complete novice at web design.  I've spent hours and hours researching jquery and css code and have tried about a dozen different things regarding this issue.  There seems to be no real solid solution to this problem and it's causing customer issues with usability on mobile platforms.  Here is my website [www.greenenvysuppy.com](http://www.greenenvysupply.com) thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is make a seperate menu for desktop and mobile. Hide the desktop one from small devices and hide the mobile one from larger devices.

Then you can have the desktop menu have the hover functionality you want and on the mobile version you let it work on click.

On the mobile devices you add the parent menu link to the sub menu as the top link. This way by clicking the parent menu the menu will slide open and close as the user should rely on it doing and when they want to go to the parent menu link they simply click the first link.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! That all makes sense.  However, instead of hiding the menus from the devices based on size, is it possible to do it based on whether the device has a touch screen or not?  

Best.